# Any use case of communication of nodes on different netowkrs?

Tags: ros, master

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to know if there are use cases that nodes on different(distributed) networks communicate with each other, using single ROS Master.

It's like:

- PC A on Network A: ROS Master and node A(A1, A2...)
- PC B on Network B: Node B(B1, B2...)
- (PC C on network C: Node C)

I heard Rapyuta was true of this case.
If you know something about this, let me know!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224291/any-use-case-of-communication-of-nodes-on-different-netowkrs?/) by [Lain Iwakura](https://answers.ros.org/users/25630/lain-iwakura/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-01-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2016-01-27**:
Rapyuta is not exactly what you mention as it is not using a single ROS master. However, it might still be useful for your case: http://rapyuta.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS can communicate across networks as long as they are routeable.

Many users use a VPN to connect robots across private networks.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1